# Select the Group of TreeView

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, binding, treeview

Is it possible to select a Group in a TreeView like an Item in the List?

I use the GroupStyle and defined a TextBlock with some styles.
So i think about an alternative, where i set something like "SelectedGroupItem" in DataContext and compare it with the GroupName to set the Background of the TextBlock to display, that the group is selected, but i can not bind the "Value"-Property of the DataTrigger to the GroupName or Text of TextBox, because its only support DependencyProperties.

Sry for my bad english.
I hope u understand my problem.